# Creating a while loop which insert json data into sqlite (Android)

Tags: android, json, sqlite, do-while

Basically I am trying to insert the JSON objects the app received into the SQLite database. As I named my JSON object in a continuous ID, I want to create a do while loop to count how many objects it received and stop when the maximum object is received.

My codes is following:

```
    mydb.StoreMemberInfo(Integer.valueOf(json.getString(TAG_MEMBER_ID).toString()), json.getString(TAG_MEMBER_NAME), Integer.valueOf(json.getString(TAG_MEMBER_POINT).toString()));
                do {
                    mydb.StoreShopInfo(Integer.valueOf(json.getString(TAG_SHOP_ID + ++shop_ID_counter).toString()), json.getString(TAG_SHOP_NAME + ++shop_name_counter));
                }
                while(TAG_SHOP_ID + shop_ID_counter != null);
```

The JSON objects my app is supposed to receive is as following:

```
    {"success":1,"message":"Login successful","member_id":"1","member_name":"Peter","member_point":"1000","shop_ID_1":"1","shop_name_1":"Chatime","shop_ID_2":"2","shop_name_2":"Beard Papa","shop_ID_3":"3","shop_name_3":"CoolBlog","friend_ID_1":"2","friend_name_1":"James","friend_ID_2":"3","friend_name_2":"Mary"}
```

The loop is supposed to stop once it reached shop_ID_4 but because it does not exist but the code is in a waiting state and does not process the other codes instead. What should I do?

Comment: I want the loop to end when it detects no such JSON object exist which I thought null is a sensible condition. Turned out its not.

Comment: I don't understand. How is it supposed to understand the *no JSON exists* condition ?

Comment: Also, personally if I knew the exact values that should be coming back I would just make a parser for them directly.

Comment: So basically what I want to achieve is when there are a number of JSON objects being passed to the app, I want it to insert the exact amount of objects into the database and stop after it finish. In this example there are 3 shop IDs and I want to create a loop to read the 3 IDs and stop after.

Comment: @AshleyAlvarado the thing is the value is not constant. It depends on the data in the database. That's why I wanted to use a loop.

Comment: I see Ok, going to put some code below that I am using for something similar.

Answer (score 0):

Can be worked on to do what you need I believe.  Just copy and pasted from something I did a few months ago.

```
 public List<LocationData> parseLocatonData(String response)
        {
            String result = response;
            mLocationData = new ArrayList<LocationData>();
            try {

                JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(result);
                Boolean status = jsonObject.getBoolean("status");
                if (status) {
                    JSONObject jObject = new JSONObject();
                    jObject = jsonObject.getJSONObject("results");
                    Iterator<String> keys = jObject.keys();

                    while (keys.hasNext()) {
                        LocationData locationData = new LocationData();
                        String key = keys.next();
                        JSONObject innerJObject = jObject.getJSONObject(key);

                        locationData.setLocationName(innerJObject.getString("cName"));
                        locationData.setCity(innerJObject.getString("cCity"));
                        locationData.setAddress(innerJObject.getString("cAddress"));
                        locationData.setFieldName(innerJObject.getString("cField"));
                        locationData.setState(innerJObject.getString("cState"));
                        locationData.setFieldUrl(innerJObject.getString("cWebsite"));
                        locationData.setZip(innerJObject.getString("cZip"));

                        mLocationData.add(locationData);
                    }
                    return mLocationData;
                }

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                Toast.makeText(mContext, "Error getting Location Info", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                LogUtils.LOGI(TAG, e.toString());
            }
            return null;
        }
```

The main thing is the key iterator, lets you walk down the list

Comment: I will give it a try! Thanks a lot for your help! :)